# Learn UML but from C# perspective... (i'm beginner)

Tags: c#, .net, uml

I need to learn UML but from a C# perspective.

I'm beginner with C# language, so I don't have any experience in C/C++ and other languages.

I'm a freshstart learner with C#.

So I check google/books but they explain with VB/JAVA code and other IDEs.

I need to find a book or extensive page about learn UML with C#.

I know a little about it, I think is a flowing mechanism of steps to develop a program. But I have a really little time and I want to get a Good idea using UML with C# exclusively for being useful at an easy project.

Could you help me?

Comment: The IDE for VB(.NET) and C# will be nearly identical and syntax between Java and C# is close enough that you should be able to use any Java source as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you take a look at Martin Fowler's book, "Uml Distilled".  That should give you a good grasp of the basics.

One of the hardest things I had to get my head around with Uml is the concept of different "views".  Some of the uml notations are used for one diagram and not for others.

I would start by trying to learn about class diagrams as this has the closest mapping to what you see in C#; Class, Object, Interfaces, etc.

Some of the diagrams, such as Use Case, have nothing to do with programming languages or concepts and will work with any programming language.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking seems a bit awkward (that is, if we are both talking about the same thing: Unified Modeling Language).

From my understanding of UML, it is mostly a way of representing high level concepts and is not language specific.

If you want my opinion, an advanced knowledge of Object Oriented programming should be sufficient for whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

UML is language agnostic, that is its very purpose but of course in the end you'll need to reify it in a language. If it is C# you can type C# UML and you'll get plenty of links like this one:

http://www.excelsoftware.com/csharp_models.pdf

Now the problem I see with many of these resources is that they tend to just focus on class diagrams. Whereas UML is more than just that. I'd advise you to focus on UML Use Case first because that's where business requirements starts. See for example an e-commerce example here:
http://www.dzone.com/links/r/ecommerce_umlyuml_use_case_diagram.html

Answer (score 0):

UML is not programming language specific.  As Monti said, take a look at the UML Distilled book as well as some of the tutorials linked on the Object Management Group's page ([http://www.uml.org/](http://www.uml.org)).  There are some decent UML online tutorials from companies such as Sparx that make UML tools.  These tutorials are not tool specific so you should be able to get a fair amount of information from them.

[Sparx Resources](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/links.html)

[VisualCase Tutorial](http://www.visualcase.com/tutorials/uml-tutorial.htm)